# Binding broken for Mode = OneWay on direct value assignment to DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, dependency-properties

I have a very simple piece of code to understand the behavior that what happens when we have assigned a Binding expression to any dependency property and then assign a direct value to that dependency property. Following is code

**View XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Assign binding value" />
    <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Content="Assign direct value" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding TextSource, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="stf" />
</StackPanel>
```

**View XAML.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MainViewViewModel vm = new MainViewViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = vm;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.TextSource = "Value set using binding";
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        stf.Text = "New direct value";
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainViewViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //INotifypropertychanged implementation here ...

    private string _textSource;

    public string TextSource
    {
        get { return _textSource; }
        set
        {
            _textSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TextSource");
        }
    }

}
```

Now my observation is

1. When I click "Assign binding value" the view is updated with binding source value. (**As expected**)
2. When I click "Assign direct value" the view is updated with the direct value assigned to text field (**As expected**)
3. I assume that at this stage the binding is broken and when I click on "Assign binding value" again it should not work, mean no UI update. and it works according to my expectations (**As expected**)
4. The confusing point is when I set the binding mode to "TwoWay", then point 3 is not happening, and it always keeps working whatever button I press. both from binding source and direct value. (**Not clear to me what TwoWay binding need to do with this**)

Anyone please clarify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While setting `DependencyProperty` value, `DependencyObject` checks if the new value is the `BindingExpression` or not. If not it checks if the previous value was the binding expression. For previous binding expression it tries to set the value for the expression. BindingExpression while trying to set the value checks the mode, and for OneWay it returns false without setting the value and  deactivates and detaches the binding expression for the dependency property. Hence for `Mode=OnWay`, binding gets deactivated and detached for a dependency property.

For `TwoWay`, since `BindingExpression` is able to set the value, hence binding is not deactivated and continues to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please let me know some reference documentation link for this so I can read it in details? Moreover If we have a custom dependency property in a custom control, Is it our responsibility to do these checks in `DependencyPropertyChanged` event or it is done before that?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no reference as such, but you can reflect on DependencyObject SetValue function to see what all steps it takes to set the DP value. No, you need not be worried about these checks as these will be taken care for you by DependencyObject base class.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `TwoWay` binding will assign the value of the property in the View Model to the dependency property of the UI element, **and also** if you change at any point the value of the dependency property (like when you press the button "Assign direct value") then the new value of the dependency property will also be assigned to the property in the View Model.

In other words I think `TowWay` mode actually means that the value can be assigned from the View Model to the UI and from the UI to the View Model.

Comment: Yes indeed two way binding is for both directions but then why for OneWay binding the source -> target update is not working when I have assigned direct value to `TextField.Text`. In both cases I am testing source->target.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think what you said in the original post is true, when assigning direct value to `TextField.Text` the binding gets broken (although I have never seen such a thing). To be honest I would have to test this scenario myself to discuss more about it. Sorry If I wasn't of much help.